# Orchard: Preserving data from Vandelay.Meta (1.0) in upgrade to Vandelay Industries (1.8)

Tags: meta-tags, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

Been using the excellent Vandelay.Meta 1.0 module with Orchard 1.7. Recently upgraded to 1.81 and decided to also upgrade to Vandelay Industries 1.8 module, which includes meta.

I disabled the old module and the new module installed without issue. My data (100+ pages) now exists in the old Vandelay_Meta_MetaRecord table while the new Vandelay_Industries_MetaRecord table is empty. How do I get my old data into the new module and back on my pages?

I can confirm that new meta entries are being written to the new table. I also tried manually copying a few record from the old to the new table. Pages do not use them. Guessing the new object cache is at play.

Thanks. Coooooooooo-stanza!

Answer (score 0):

If you were updating a module, you should have not disabled it first.
 Orchard uses migrations to update your modules and keep your data sound.
Or i might be missing something